# Python write to file creating empty file

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I try to create and write to a text file only an empty file is created. Here is the code:

```
controlCheck = open("resources/controlType.txt", "w")
controlCheck.write("controller")
controlCheck.close()
```

Any idea what the problem is? Its driving me crazy.

Comment: Not reproducible. Is this the entire code?

Comment: Its part of a much larger Tkinter program but that is the only time controlCheck is accessed.

Comment: Is it within a `try: except` block or something?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878628/opening-a-file-for-append. Also, @the_crevis, look up your question before asking it. More often than not, questions like this have already been answered several times.

Comment: As a general rule you should use ``with open("resources/controlType.txt", "w") as controlCheck:`` instead of manually opening/closing the file.

Comment: I have found the error! I was using the variable name controlCheck elsewhere which was interfering without showing the error :S Thanks for trying to help, always the simplest mistake which takes a long time to notice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever python writes a file, it erases all former data.There are ways to get around it, such as using: what is talked about here: [Opening a file for append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878628/opening-a-file-for-append)

Comment: That only answers the question if it's being checked during it being open. It should contain ``'controller'`` after the close.