# Why doesn't Python write to the file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have programmed a small password generator where you can save the password and its service on a file named "password.txt". Everytime I run the program, the file remains blank. When I delete the file and run the program again, the file "password.txt" is created but is still blank.

```
import random

letters = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 Q W E R T Z U I O P A S D F G H J K L Y X C V B N M q w e r t z u i o p a s d f g h j k l y x c v b n m : ; , . 0".split()

def checkNumb(string):
    for i in string:
        x = i.isdigit()
        if x == True:
            return True

def createPassword():
    global letters
    password = ""
    i = 0
    passLength = random.randint(7, 10)
    while i < passLength:
        passLetter = random.choice(letters)
        password += passLetter
        i += 1
    x = checkNumb(password)
    if x != True:
        password = createPassword()
    return password

print("What is the name of the service?")
service = input()
password = createPassword()
print(password, "will be your password for", service)

file = open("password.txt","a")
file.write(service + ": " + password)
file.close()
```

Also, because I am a beginner, it would be a great help if someone could point out a few improvements I can do in this code.

EDIT : The indentation error on the while statement was just a mistake I made while copying the code to here. The program has no indentation errors. Thanks asongtoruin for reminding me.

Comment: not sure if this is from copying the code to SO but your indents are off - the `while i < passLenght:` should be in line with the line above it.

Comment: This program won't even run. Can you check the indentation please? Badly indented Python code is nonsense.

Comment: After I fixed the indentation of the while loop, i had a `password.txt` with the desired text in it...

Comment: Fix the indent, then it works nicely

Answer (score 1):

Just a small indentation error

```
import random

letters = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 Q W E R T Z U I O P A S D F G H J K L Y X C V B N M q w e r t z u i o p a s d f g h j k l y x c v b n m : ; , . 0".split()

def checkNumb(string):
    for i in string:
        x = i.isdigit()
        if x == True:
            return True

def createPassword():
    global letters
    password = ""
    i = 0
    passLenght = random.randint(7, 10)
    while i < passLenght:
        passLetter = random.choice(letters)
        password += passLetter
        i += 1
    x = checkNumb(password)
    if x != True:
        password = createPassword()
    return password

print("What is the name of the service?")
service = input()
password = createPassword()
print(password, "will be your password for", service)

file = open("password.txt","a")
file.write(service + ": " + password)
file.close()
```

This works, look at the while indentation in createPassword()

Output

```
python write_file.py
What is the name of the service?
service1
SCawELnU7f will be your password for service1
```

File Content:

```
service1: uj.voSK38
```

Also refer to this link, for file appending difference

[Opening a file for append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878628/opening-a-file-for-append)

Comment: The indentation is not in the program. I accidently added it in while writting it  here at stackoverflow's editor. I edited my post. Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Tested code with `while i < passLenght:` dedented once and it worked as inteneded